# Getting isotopejs running on requirejs... or not. Dependencies?

Tags: gruntjs, requirejs, dependencies, jquery-isotope

at the moment I'm fighting with Isotopejs & requirejs. As a Designer like me those things with modules and dependencies are scarying me ;)

I'm trying to get this running: 
http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/mEinp

**Here my `require-config.js` :**

```
(function (global, require) {
  'use strict';

  require.config({
    baseUrl: './webroot/js',
    catchError: true,
    paths: {
      'site-core': './modules/shared/site-core',
      'isotope': './vendor/isotope/dist/isotope.pkgd',
      'jquery-bridget': './vendor/jquery-bridget/jquery-bridget',
      'jquery': './vendor/jquery.min',
      'bootstrap': './vendor/bootstrap/bootstrap'    
    },
    shim: {
      'jquery': {
        exports: 'jQuery'
      }
    }
  });

})(this, require);
```

The File where I want to launch the isotope Gallery is following:

```
'use strict';
// require the require function
require(['require', 'jquery', 'isotope'],
  function (require, $, Isotope) {
    require(['jquery-bridget'],
      function () {
        // make Isotope a jQuery plugin
        $.bridget('isotope', Isotope);
        // now you can use $().isotope()
        $('.grid').isotope({
          itemSelector: '.grid-item',
          masonry: {
            columnWidth: 100
          }
        });
      }
    );
  }
);
```

[Thats what it looks like, at the moment. As you can see my console is filled with dependency(?) errors.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eS4uE.png)

- Modules: layout-modes/masonry Error: Script error for "layout-modes/masonry"(…)
- Modules: layout-modes/fit-rows Error: Script error for "layout-modes/fit-rows"(…)
- Modules: item Error: Script error for "item"
- Modules: layout-mode Error: Script error for "layout-mode"(…)
- Modules: layout-modes/vertical Error: Script error for "layout-modes/vertical"(…)

I've been juggling around with modules, the isotope API and I'm still stuck. Does somebody see where the Problem is? I don't have a clue anymore. I hope someone of you is able you point me the right direction.

Have a nice day und thank you!
Seb.